# Trouble getting standard output in Java from a C program with getchar()

Tags: java, c, inputstream

I'm trying to call a C program from Java and capture the standard output.  Here is my code:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("helloworld.exe");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);   // Merge std out and std err into same stream
    program = pb.start();           // Start program

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(program.getInputStream()));

    line = input.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = input.readLine();
    }   
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is a sample c program:

```
int main(){
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

This works fine when the program I'm executing (helloworld in this case) does not have a `getchar()` in it.  However, if I add a `getchar()` right after the printf, I never get anything off the input stream.  Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: haven't worked with c for awhile, but you may want to try to flush the output stream after the print

Comment: Have you tried running your c program on its own to see if it's generating an error or what the behavior is?

Comment: Why would you add `getchar` to a program that does not need input? ???

Comment: where are you writing to the C program's stdin? (because if you're not writing anything to it, of course getchar() will block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kyle you said, you may need to flush the output stream after calling print to make sure the characters actually go to the standard output without delay.  You should do this in both programs.  This can be done in C with `fflush(stdout);` and can probably be done in Java with something like `System.out.flush()`.

--David

Comment: I added fflush(NULL) right after the printf in the c program and it solved the problem.  Thanks Kyle and David.

Answer (score 1):

Because when the C program calls getchar, the C program stops to wait for input. And the input never comes! After all, your Java program captures stdout/stderr, but does nothing about attaching to stdin.

Use the [getOutputStream() instance method in the Process class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) on your `program` object to get the stream representing stdin, analogous to getInputStream().

Then send the data to the C program that the C program expects.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the child process (or the OS or the JAVA Runtime or ..., ...) is still waiting for a char (the `getchar`) before sending the output to the parent process.

If you don't need input, don't include the `getchar`!!